Is birthday attack sufficient to prove that a hash function is collision-resistant?
Suppose we have the hash function: $H_3^s(x\cdot y) = F_s(x) \oplus y$, where $F_s(\cdot)$ is a pseudo-random function, $\oplus$ is the bitwise xor and $x \cdot y$ means $x$ concatenated with $y$.
I tried proving that this is a collision-resistant hash function with this reasoning: because of the birthday problem, given $q$ uniformly chosen random values in a finite set of cardinality $N$, the probability that two of them are identical is $\Theta(\frac{q^2}{N})$. So, in this case, $q=2^{|x| + |y|} = 2^{|x \cdot y|}$, and $N = 2^n$.
So, the probability of collision becomes:
$P_{\text{collision}}=\Theta(\frac{2^{2|x \cdot y|}}{2^n}) = \Theta(2^{2|x\cdot y|-n})$.
Now, we want the probability of finding a collision to be negligible: $P_{\text{collision}}= \Theta(2^{2|x\cdot y | - n})< \epsilon(n)$
To ensure this, the expression simplify to:
$2^{2|x\cdot y|-n}\leq \epsilon(n)$
Now, taking the $2$-log:
$2|x\cdot y|-n \leq \log_2 \epsilon(n)$
$|x \cdot y| \leq \frac{n}{2} + \frac{log_2\epsilon(n)}{2}$
And this condition assures the collision-resistance of $H_3^s$.
Is all of this correct? Does this mean that $H_3^s$ is collision-resistant in general?

I doubt it. If you pick any $x_0\ne x_1$ and any $y_0$, which condition on $y_1$ do you get if there is a collision between $x_0\cdot y_0$ and $x_1\cdot y_1$?

Succumbing to the birthday attack proves that the function is not collision resistant. Resisting the birthday attack is necessary, but not sufficient for the function to be collision-resistant. Thus neither succumbing to nor resisting the birthday attack can ever prove that a hash function is collision-resistant.


Does this mean that $H_3^s$ is collision-resistant in general?

No.  What collision-resistant means is that it is computationally infeasible to find a collision.  The adversary is not restricted to just selecting random values and hashing them; they can also (for example) observe the outputs, and use those to deduce collisions.
For example, if the attacker hashes the values:
$$z_1 = H_3^s(x_1 \cdot 0)$$
$$z_2 = H_3^s(x_2 \cdot 0)$$
He can immediately deduce that this equality holds
$$z_1 = H_3^s(x_2 \cdot (z_1 \oplus z_2))$$
Thus yielding a collision.  This is true even if the adversary doesn't know the value $s$.
